# wpf & validation application block > message localization > messageTemplateResource Name&Type

Tags: wpf, validation, localization, resources, enterprise-library

I'm trying to write validation rules for my data objects in a **WPF application**. I'm writing them in the configuration file, and so far they are working fine.

I'm stumped on how to localize the messages using messageTemplateResourceName and messageTemplateResourceType. What I know is that the strings can be writen in a resource file, given a name and referenced by that name. I get the idea, but i haven't been able to make this work.

```
<ruleset name="Rule Set">
    <properties>
        <property name="StringValue">
            <validator lowerBound="0" lowerBoundType="Ignore" upperBound="25"
          upperBoundType="Inclusive" negated="false" messageTemplate=""
          messageTemplateResourceName="msg1" messageTemplateResourceType="Resources"
          tag=""  
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.StringLengthValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation"
          name="String Length Validator" />
         </property>
    </properties>
</ruleset>
```

**Where is the resource file and what value do I pass to messageTemplateResourceType?**
I have tried writing the messages in the shell project's resource file but no sucess trying to retrieve the value. I only get the default built-in message.

I've tried

- messageTemplateResourceType="typeof(Resources)"
- messageTemplateResourceType="Resources"
- messageTemplateResourceType="Resources.resx"
- messageTemplateResourceType="typeof(Shell)"
- messageTemplateResourceType="Shell"
- messageTemplateResourceType="Shell,
  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=null"

I've also tried adding a new resource file in the shell project, and adding a resource file to the data object's library. I'm all out of ideas **Does anyone have any suggestions?** I'm not even married to the idea of resource files, so if there are other ways to localize these messages I'd love to know!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own resource file and then point the messageTemplateResourceType attribute to your fully qualified resource type.  As long as the resource file can be loaded at runtime you should be fine.

```
<ruleset name="Rule Set">
  ...
  messageTemplateResourceName="msg1"  
  messageTemplateResourceType="My.Fully.Qualified.ResourceType, My.AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
  ...
</ruleset>
```

An alternate way to do it would be use the messageTemplate as a key and write custom code to look up the actual localized string based on the messageTemplate key (either from a resource file or from a database or wherever else you are storing it).

Comment: thanks, seemed my assembly name was not what I thought it was.